# Proving convergence of real sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Having already shown that $$\lim_{n\to \infty } \left ( \left (1+\frac{1}{n} \right )^n \right ) $$ exists I am then asked to show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty } \left ( \left (1-\frac{1}{n} \right )^n \right ) $$ exists.

Is there a way of linking the two limits together and the convergence of the first convergence implies the convergence of the second sequence.?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the exponential and logarithm functions?

Answer (score 7):

It is enough to prove $\displaystyle\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)^n\Bigl(1-\frac1n\Bigr)^n$ has a limit.
$$\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)^n\Bigl(1-\frac1n\Bigr)^n=\Bigl(1-\frac1{n^2}\Bigr)^n<1$$
and by *Bernoulli's inequality*, we have
$$\Bigl(1-\frac1{n^2}\Bigr)^n\ge 1-n\cdot\frac1{n^2}=1-\frac1n.$$
The *squeeze theorem* ensures that
$$\lim_n\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)^n\Bigl(1-\frac1n\Bigr)^n=1,$$
so that $$\lim_n\Bigl(1-\frac1n\Bigr)^n=\frac1{\lim_n\Bigl(1+\dfrac1n\Bigr)^n}.$$

Comment: Note that technically we'd need to also show that the limit of $(1+1/n)^n$ is nonzero (which of course it is, but OP may not already have shown it (somehow?)).

Comment: @Richard Rast: It's obvious since all $(1+1/n) >1$. Actually I implicitly supposed he did know the limit.

Comment: Yes, I do know the limit, but at this stage in the course we haven't proved the limit and so cannot say exactly what it is, although it is easy to show that the limit is in fact greater than 1 and hence nonzero.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n  =  \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^n} = \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{n-1+1}{n-1}\right)^n} = \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^n} = \left(\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}}\right)\left(\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n-1}}\right) = \frac{1}{\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}} = \frac{1}{\lim_{m \to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^{m}}$$
where I substituted $m = n-1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Write
$$\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n = \dfrac{1}{\left(\dfrac{n}{n-1}\right)^n}$$